# How can I scroll to a specific location on the page using jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto, jquery-scrollable

Is it possible to scroll to a specific location on the page using jQuery?

Does the location I want to scroll to have to have:

```
<a name="#123">here</a>
```

Or can it just move to a specific DOM id?

Comment: just a small note: attribute "name" is not allowed in XHTML 1.1 Strict, use an ID instead

Comment: interesting question, can't use page coordinates to scroll? I think we should be able to.

Comment: I got solution similar to your requirement at [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432656/scroll-to-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: @mrblah does your problem resolved?

Answer (score 242):

**jQuery Scroll Plugin**

since this is a question tagged with **jquery** i have to say, that this library has a very nice plugin for smooth scrolling, you can find it here:
http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollTo/

Excerpts from Documentation:

```
$('div.pane').scrollTo(...);//all divs w/class pane
```

or

```
$.scrollTo(...);//the plugin will take care of this
```

**Custom jQuery function for scrolling**

you can use a very **lightweight approach** by defining your custom scroll jquery function

```
$.fn.scrollView = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

and use it like:

```
$('#your-div').scrollView();
```

**Scroll to a page coordinates**

Animate `html` and `body` elements with `scrollTop` or `scrollLeft` attributes

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0,
    scrollLeft: 300
}, 1000);
```

**Plain javascript**

scrolling with `window.scroll`

```
window.scroll(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
```

only to sum up, use the window.location.hash to jump to element with ID

```
window.location.hash = '#your-page-element';
```

**Directly in HTML (accesibility enhancements)**

```
<a href="#your-page-element">Jump to ID</a>

<div id="your-page-element">
    will jump here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Juraj Blahunka, but I do this without any plugin

Comment: The link is not taking me to *ScrollTo*. Can you update it please?

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 130):

Yep, even in plain JavaScript it's pretty easy. You give an element an id and then you can use that as a "bookmark":

```
<div id="here">here</div>
```

If you want it to scroll there when a user clicks a link, you can just use the tried-and-true method:

```
<a href="#here">scroll to over there</a>
```

To do it programmatically, use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

```
document.getElementById("here").scrollIntoView()
```

Comment: @nickf This is not supported yet everywhere. http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView

Comment: This i def supported (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Think you didn't read the caniuse properly. However, won't be animated. Rather a pretty abrupt jump which isn't always great.

Answer (score 56):

There is no need to use any plugin, you can do it like this:

```
var divPosition = $('#divId').offset();
```

then use this to scroll document to specific DOM:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "slow");
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the best answer. Not much code and does not require a plugin.

Comment: Note that you might need to recalculate the offset on window resize.

Comment: @BartBurg good point-- or just recalculate right before the `.animate` call happens

Comment: Love the simple answer. Why do people have to make things so complicated? Don't want another plugin.

Comment: Indeed the best answer.

Answer (score 21):

Here's a pure javascript version:

```
location.hash = '#123';
```

It'll scroll automatically.
Remember to add the "#" prefix.

Comment: Using the primitive way of named anchor, you can have URL that includes the hash E.g. http://www.mywebsite.com/page-about/#123
Bookmarking includes the hash + scrollintoview behaviour too.

Comment: Would be great if you can explain a little

Answer (score 7):

Plain Javascript:

```
window.location = "#elementId"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="idVal">
    <!--div content goes here-->
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var divLoc = $('#idVal').offset();
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divLoc.top}, "slow");
     });
</script>
```

This example shows to locate to a particular div id i.e, 'idVal' in this case. If you have subsequent divs/tables that will open up in this page via ajax, then you can assign unique divs and call the script to scroll to the particular location for each contents of divs.

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".scroll-element").click(function(){
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.our_companies').offset().top
            }, 1000);

            return false;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It would be great if you add some comments to your code. How does it helps the asker to solve their question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="divRegister"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
location.hash = "divRegister";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is variant of @juraj-blahunka's **lightweight approach**. This function does not assume the container is the document and only scrolls if the item is out of view. Animation queuing is also disabled to avoid unnecessary bouncing.

```
$.fn.scrollToView = function () {
    return $.each(this, function () {
        if ($(this).position().top < 0 ||
            $(this).position().top + $(this).height() > $(this).parent().height()) {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).parent().scrollTop() + $(this).position().top
            }, {
                duration: 300,
                queue: false
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I had the bounce issue, but your method doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery.easing.min.js, With fixed IE console Errors

**Html**

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
<section id="features" class="features-section">Features Section</section>


        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

**Jquery**

```
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll, you can use this code with in external file with name scrolling-nav.js
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
            } else {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
            }
        });
        //jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
        $(function () {
            $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function (event) {
                var anchor = $(this);
                if ($(anchor).length > 0) {
                    var href = $(anchor).attr('href');
                    if ($(href.substring(href.indexOf('#'))).length > 0) {
                        $('html, body').stop().animate({
                            scrollTop: $(href.substring(href.indexOf('#'))).offset().top
                        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location = href;
                    }
                }
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Comment: That is way too much code for such a simple task. `location.hash = 'idOfElement';` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to get this done without Javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: scroll-behavior: smooth; is not browser compatible property.

Comment: check the browser compatibility lower in the link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes given table in your links is showing: Edge, IE and safari are not compatible with this property.