# How to go to a specific element on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my HTML page, I want to be able to 'go to' / 'scroll to' / 'focus on' an element on the page.

Normally, I'd use an anchor tag with a `href="#something"`, but I'm already using the hashchange event along with the [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to load this page.

So is there any other way, via JavaScript, to have the page go to a given element on the page?

Here's the basic outline of what I'm trying to do:

```
function focusOnElement(element_id) {
     $('#div_' + element_id).goTo(); // need to 'go to' this element
}

<div id="div_element1">
   yadda yadda 
</div>
<div id="div_element2">
   blah blah
</div>

<span onclick="focusOnElement('element1');">Click here to go to element 1</span>
<span onclick="focusOnElement('element2');">Click here to go to element 2</span>
```

Comment: My honest suggestion is dropping the BBQ plugin. What a terrible idea, destroying expected default behaviour for a silly storage mechanism.

Comment: We're using the BBQ plugin for a slideshow, which is the central feature of this page.  The plugin allows us to fetch the next item via Ajax without needing to repost the rest of the page.  In this case, the BBQ plugin is kind of crucial.

Comment: if you still use StackOverflow, it might be worth updating the answer to the more popular, native one.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The standard technique in plugin form would look something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.goTo = function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px'
        }, 'fast');
        return this; // for chaining...
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then you could just say `$('#div_element2').goTo();` to scroll to `<div id="div_element2">`. Options handling and configurability is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: One question is, why would you animate 'html, body' and not just 'body'?

Comment: @Lior: Honestly, I do that now because I've always done it that way; I think the original reason for `'html,body'` is to deal with browser differences.

Comment: I added a variable so that, if there was say a header that the element was still under, I can pass a negative to stop the scroll earlier: **usage:** `$('#element').goTo(-50);`  **function:**
`(function ($) {
    $.fn.goTo = function (addToScroll) {
        if (!addToScroll) { addToScroll = 0; }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($(this).offset().top + addToScroll) + 'px'
        }, 'fast');
        return this; // for chaining...
    }
})(jQuery);`

Answer (score 216):

If the element is currently not visible on the page, you can use the native [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) method.

```
$('#div_' + element_id)[0].scrollIntoView( true );
```

Where `true` means align to the top of the page, and `false` is align to bottom.

Otherwise, there's [a `scrollTo()` plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) for jQuery you can use.

Or maybe just get the `top` [`position()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/position/) of the element, and set the [`scrollTop()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to that position:

```
var top = $('#div_' + element_id).position().top;
$(window).scrollTop( top );
```

Comment: +1 for the native scrollIntoView which i didnt know at all. for a moment i thought it was jquery. :)

Comment: @yetanothercode: Thanks for adding the MDN link. I was a little to lazy last night. :o)

Comment: `position().top` is not correct because it is relative to the parent element. You shall use `offset().top` which is relative to the document.

Comment: I combined this with the accepted answer with great results: 

`function($) { $.fn.goTo = function() { $(this)[0].scrollIntoView(true); return this; // for chaining... } 
})(jQuery);`

Comment: Thanks for native answer, but UX of this feature is terrible. [There is even an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9446004/2559709) about how bad is it.

Comment: thanks for native answer, but not very configurable where I want top-150px to center in the list

Comment: from MDN: `scrollIntoView is experimental technology` and from their compatibility only work on firefox

Answer (score 171):

```
document.getElementById("elementID").scrollIntoView();
```

Same thing, but wrapping it in a function:

```
function scrollIntoView(eleID) {
   var e = document.getElementById(eleID);
   if (!!e && e.scrollIntoView) {
       e.scrollIntoView();
   }
}
```

This even works in an IFrame on an iPhone.

Example of using getElementById:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid

Comment: Simple, works well in jQueryMobile where hash tags can be problematic.

Comment: sweeeet. simple and works on iphone

Comment: as of 2016, `scrollIntoView()` is technically non-standard ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)), but you can pretty much use it everywhere anyway ([ref](http://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview)).

Comment: `scrollIntoView()` appears to have wide support except for the "smooth" parameter according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview)

Comment: It doesn't scroll. It just throws you on top. No any scrolling. How to animate it?

Comment: This is a base JavaScript method and doesn't animate.  However, it doesn't need a framework (e.g. JQuery) to run.  If you want animation,  use something like is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery

Comment: It's important to note it has very limited support across browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: As answered before,  limited support is for the extensions to the scrollIntoView("option") - not the basic scrollIntoView() method which is supported by all browsers.

Comment: no need for " !! " - js if statements already check for truthiness

Comment: `!!` is a check for nulls - if `e` is null then `e.scrollIntoView()` will hurl.

Answer (score 21):

To scroll to a *specific element on your page*, you can add a function into your `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...})` as follows:

```
$("#fromTHIS").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#toTHIS").offset().top }, 500);
    return true;
});
```

It works like a charm in all browsers. Adjust the speed according to your need.