# Do the Scrolling in Client Brower Window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
Can i handle the browser scroll bar.
```

Cause my Aspx Page is to large.suppose if i hit a button on top so i want to set focus a control which is at the near bottom.

```
Is this Possible to scroll till that control...
```

---

**Modified RequireMent**.
Can a linkbutton in gridcontrol navigate to itself with setting the focus to control[Panel] on bottom of the page.

Comment: do you want your links to point within your page? Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a button, then add an OnClick handler that calls a javascript function like this :

```
function pageScroll() {
         window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
         var control = document.getElementById("yourControlName");
         if( control != null ){control.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
<a href='#myRequiredControl'>Go to my control</a>
.....lots of html in between.....
<div id='myControl'><a name='myRequiredControl'></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can get the position of the specific element on screen and programmatically scroll to that position.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-specific-to-element-on-page) answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the good ol' `<a name="somewhereWayDown" />` (target) and `<a href="#somewhereWayDown">go waaaay down</a>`?

... and for a bonus, add links back to the top:

```
<a name="top" />
<a href="#somewhereWayDown"></a>

<!-- lots of content here -->

<a name="somewherewaydown" />
<!-- some interesting content here -->
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>

<!-- even more content -->
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```