# How to scroll within an overflow hidden div to a certain currently invisible element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a list of elements within a overflow hidden div. So not all elements are visible. Now, if an element gets activated, it should become visible within the div.

How do I scroll to the active element using jQuery?

It's merely a convenience that the last element has the active class. It will be toggled dynamically.

```js
 var scrollToEl = $("div.element.active");
 console.log(zoomToEl);
```

```css
 #main,
 #sidebar {
   height: 200px;
 }
 #wrapper {
   width: 190px;
   float: left;
   background: grey;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 #sidebar div.element {
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   background-color: green;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 #sidebar div.element.active {
   background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper" class="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div class="element" data-slide-id="0">a
      </div>
      <div class="element" data-slide-id="1">b
      </div>
      <div class="element" data-slide-id="2">c
      </div>
      <div class="element" data-slide-id="3">d
      </div>
      <div class="element" data-slide-id="4">e
      </div>
      <div class="element" data-slide-id="5">f
      </div>
      <div class="element" data-slide-id="6">g
      </div>
      <div class="element active" data-slide-id="7">h
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The element that should become visible:

```
var scrollToEl = $("div.element.active");
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) of the wrapper div to be the `top` of the [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) of the active element.

```
$("#wrapper").scrollTop($("#wrapper").scrollTop() + $("div.element.active").position().top);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuFk5/250/)

Comment: Tried your demo but it only works once, try repeating it and you'll see some strange behaviour. This seems to be fixed by the following code: $("#wrapper").scrollTop($("#wrapper").scrollTop() + $("div.element.active").position().top); DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pA2Qh/

Comment: Good catch, @Rob! That happens because when it scrolls to the active div, it's `position.top` becomes 0. Next time you try to run that code, it'll scroll to position 0, the actual top of the container. Updated my code.

Comment: @Rob, this is great. This is the best solution for cases which have `parent: 100% height`, and/or `overflow: hidden` - which is like always, in case of mobile devices

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you are looking for [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) method.

```
scrollToEl[0].scrollIntoView();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yuFk5/14/

Comment: It seems to have a few downsides: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9446004/457268 Esp. the "simply jumps to a particular element that may as well be at the end of the page" is a deal breaker for me.

Comment: @k0pernikus You'd better annotate in the question that you are looking for animated solution. Otherwise, the method works perfectly fine and simple, IMO.

Comment: I meant no disrespect to the solution you provided. It just does not fit my needs :)

Comment: @k0pernikus Well, that makes sense. At least now you know about yet another method :)

Comment: I'm using this to simulate normal behavior of a html combo box in ExtJS.

Comment: Don't miss the note at the top of that page: "This is an experimental technology"

Comment: @EmilStenström Yeah, but it remains experimental from release of IE6 and still works well in all browsers I tried it with. As an example, there is no caution about using [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method but it still behaves differently in some mobile browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:
$("ul li a.active").get(0).scrollIntoView();