# ScrollTop does not work within DIV with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have a DIV, with hidden overflow, the whole CSS block for that DIV looks like this:

```
.mainContainer .display_box .container .row .col_4 .dPost_box{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Then, I want to make the content of the DIV scroll every time I hover onto the element. However, it won't work. I have tried jQuery.scrollTop(), as well as updating regular scrollTop, it wouldn't work. I also tried using [Smooth Scroll](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll), and [Autoscroll](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autoscroll/)
plugins but none of them would work either.
My current Javascript looks like this:

```
 function autoScroll(div){
     setInterval(function() { 
    if (div.scrollTop() < div[0].scrollHeight - div.height()){
        div.scrollTop(div.scrollTop() + 10);
    }}, 1000);
 }
 $(document).on({mouseenter: function(){
     autoScroll($(this));
 }, mouseleave: function(){        
 }}, '.dPosts_post');
```

I've also tried:

```
function autoScroll(div){
     setInterval(function() { 
    if (div.scrollTop() < div[0].scrollHeight - div.height()){
        div.scrollTop[0] +=10;
    }}, 1000);
 }
```

But nothing would work. 
Preferably, I want to make the `autoScroll` function to work, but if there are any plugins that would work, I'd be more than happy to try them out.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scroll within an overflow hidden div to a certain currently invisible element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301841/how-to-scroll-within-an-overflow-hidden-div-to-a-certain-currently-invisible-ele)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get scrollTop working, but I came of with a workaround. Here's the code, if somebody else faces similar problem in the future:

```
funnction autoScroll(div){
     //check whether the content does not fit inside the div
     if(div[0].scrollHeight>div.height()){

        //calculate how much the div needs to be scrolled
        var distance = div[0].scrollHeight - div.height() + 20;
        var topCoord = parseInt(div.css('top')); //inital top coordinate of the div
        var lineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(div.css('font-size')) * 1.5);

        //calculate approximately how many lines there are in the distance that needs scrolling
        var linesCt = distance/lineHeight; 

        //scroll the div at a pace of 2.5s per line
        div.animate({top: topCoord - distance + 'px'}, 2500 * linesCt);
     }
}
```