# How to navigate to an element in a page using javascript without changing page hash

Tags: javascript, html

I need to navigate to the element 'divElem1', on click of a button. Is it possible? 
If we enter this link in browser, `http://myUrl#divElem1`, browser will navigate to the page and to the DIV element 'divElem1'. The same behavior has to be obtained through javascript.

The hash change will not work in my application, as there are other events will be fired on hash change.
So, the following will not work.

```
document.button.onclick = function () {
    location.hash = "#divElem1";
};
```

`document.getElementById("divElem1").focus()` is also not working since the element is a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "plain" Javascript, use [scrollIntoView()](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-scrollintoview.shtml). But it really jumps to that position, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445842/does-scrollintoview-work-in-all-browsers).

Using jQuery, it can be done [jumpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163626/410699) or with some easing, as explained [here](http://erraticdev.blogspot.nl/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html).

Easing is recommended to provide a better user experience and to let visitors see and understand what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) for that:

```
document.getElementById("divElem1").scrollIntoView()
```

This doesn't give fine grain control over where exactly the target element will end up but it WILL be moved into the view-port. Even more, if the element is inside a scrollable container, both the container and the element inside it will be moved into a position so they are visible in the view-port.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks for the edit. It's always better to reference to some doucmentation ;)