# ionic 2 3, why after scrolling, value of variable doesn't change?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I was wrote this code for showing button after scrolling is more than 500px, but "showButton" didn't get new value.

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <button *ngIf="showButton">Scroll Top</button>
</ion-content>
```

my.ts file:

```
showButton= false;

onScroll($event) {    
  if ($event.scrollTop > 500) {
    console.log(this.showButton);
    this.showButton= true;
  }
}
```

This console.log shows change of "showButton", but in html it doesn't change.

"showButton" for first time get value "false" but when value change to "true" it can not listen to change, how I can solve this?

Comment: See my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658827/ionic-scroll-to-div/45658989#45658989

Comment: Thanks @JGFMK, but I didn't find solution.

Comment: <button *ngIf="showButton=='true'">Scroll Top</button> try this

Comment: i think the showbutton is not type boolean, try with a number , showButton:number= 0; and in scroll function this.showButton= 1;

Comment: if removing ngIf, does your button show?

Comment: Thanks @rashidnk but both of solution didn't work.

Comment: @Duannx yes it's shown.

Comment: can  u post all ur code ?, or print the value of showButton in html like {{showButton}} in ioncontent

Comment: Try `setTimeout(()=>{this.showButton= true;},0)` It will trigger angular change detection

Comment: @rashidnk, I tried it but it shown an error and white screen

Comment: when I scrolling the page (more than 500px) and then clicking on back btn this button shown for a moment, but why?
this shown my code is true but I can't find the problem

Comment: @Duannx i tried it : setTimeout(()=>{this.showButton= true;},0) but it works same as my code

Comment: Seem like your problem is not in these code above. Please post your full html and .ts or create a working plunker that we can play with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From the ionic docs, Scroll Events Scroll events happen outside of
>   Angular's Zones. This is for performance reasons. So if you're trying
>   to bind a value to any scroll event, it will need to be wrapped in a
>   zone.run()

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
        <button *ngIf="showButton">Scroll Top</button>
</ion-content>

    //add import in .ts file

    import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';


    //in constructor 

    constructor(
        public zone: NgZone,



    showButton= false;

    onScroll($event) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          if ($event.scrollTop > 500) {
            console.log(this.showButton);
            this.showButton = true;
          }
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Method 1) use boolean variable

    <ion-content (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
        <button *ngIf="showButton">Scroll Top</button>
    </ion-content>

    showButton:boolean= false;

    onScroll($event) {    
      if ($event.scrollTop > 500) {
        console.log(this.showButton);
        this.showButton= true;
      }
    }
```

> OR

```
//Method 2) use number variable

    <ion-content (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">
        <button *ngIf="showButton==1">Scroll Top</button>
    </ion-content>

    showButton:number= 0;

    onScroll($event) {    
      if ($event.scrollTop > 500) {
        console.log(this.showButton);
        this.showButton= 1;
      }
    }
```

Comment: "showButton" for first time get value "false" but when value change to "true" it can not listen to change, how I can solve this?