# scrollIntoView does not work in EGDE browser

Tags: javascript

I am using `scrollIntoView` javascript function to scroll down to an element. Element is a rectangle (`<rect></rect>`) inside `svg`. But this is not working at all in **Microsoft EDGE browser**.

```
this.svgDoc.getElementById('R' + this.selectedCabin.number).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'start'});
```

Could anyone has an idea about this. Much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does scrollIntoView work in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445842/does-scrollintoview-work-in-all-browsers)