# Scrolling with javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to go to a specific element on page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page)

I would like to scroll to variable p  as defined in the code below. is there a function i can use to scroll to it with javascript (not jquery).  its a list item sitting inside of a scroll-able div, inside an un-ordered list.

`var x = document.getElementsByClassName('listSection')                                                      [0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];`
  `var p = x.lastChild;`

Comment: Give scrollIntoView a shot: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView

Comment: Thanks @MattGreer if you would re-post this as an answer i will accept. I've had a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to do this didn't think it was that simple.

Comment: @ModS ok, made it into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.scrollIntoView` is probably what you are looking for. If not, it's at least worth a shot:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('listSection') [0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var p = x.lastChild;
window.scrollTo(0, p.offsetTop);
```