# Using scrollIntoView with a fixed position header

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with a header set to `position: fixed`. On one of my pages, I use `scrollIntoView(true)` on an element. My problem is that when `scrollIntoView` is called, the element gets positioned underneath the header. How would I fix this so that the element is shown just below the header?

I'm using the Bootstrap framework and the header is styled with `navbar navbar-fixed-top`.

Comment: Nice question. Thanks

Answer (score 144, accepted):

It's a bit hacky but here's a workaround.

```
var node = 'select your element';
var yourHeight = 'height of your fixed header';

// scroll to your element
node.scrollIntoView(true);

// now account for fixed header
var scrolledY = window.scrollY;

if(scrolledY){
  window.scroll(0, scrolledY - yourHeight);
}
```

Edit:

A modern workaround is to use the CSS `scroll-margin-top` property in combination with the `:target` selector. Described in detail: https://www.bram.us/2020/03/01/prevent-content-from-being-hidden-underneath-a-fixed-header-by-using-scroll-margin-top/

Comment: I was looking for this answer for days. At last found it. Cool.

Comment: You can also set a imaginary 'yourHeight' like 1000 if your header has dynamic size.

Comment: It does not work when the node is located at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You could simplify your code by doing
`window.scroll(0, node.offsetTop - yourHeight);` and not using `scrollIntoView`

Comment: It works, but it will not respect the native smooth scrolling behavior of the browser, if present.

Comment: @SanyamJain {block: 'center'} options works great on scrollIntoView - thank you! Please be warned though - MDN warns that scrollIntoViewIfNeeded should not be used in prod https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded

Comment: It is not working in firefox. Can you please guide?

Comment: Note that `scroll-margin-top` with `scrollIntoView` only works in Safari 14.1 or later, released in April 2021.

Answer (score 79):

### scroll-margin-top: $header-height;

Set the `scroll-margin-top` css property to the desired top offset, on elements that you're linking/scrolling to. (it should probably have been called scroll-offset-top.)

```css
* {
  scroll-margin-top: 100px;
}
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top) - [full browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_scroll-margin-top) - [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/arye-dov-eidelman/full/bGNEaXN)

```js
links = [...document.getElementsByClassName("js-link")]
links.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.target).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "start",
      inline: "nearest"
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header a {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0.7em;
}

* {
  scroll-margin-top: 100px;
}

p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>page title</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#p1" class="js-link" data-target="p1">1</a>
    <a href="#p2" class="js-link" data-target="p2">2</a>
    <a href="#p3" class="js-link" data-target="p3">3</a>
    <a href="#p4" class="js-link" data-target="p4">4</a>
    <a href="#p5" class="js-link" data-target="p5">5</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <p id="p1">
    paragraph 1.
    <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  </p>
  <p id="p2">
    paragraph 2.
    <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  </p>
  <p id="p3">
    paragraph 3.
    <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  </p>
  <p id="p4">
    paragraph 4.
    <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  </p>
  <p id="p5">
    paragraph 5.
    <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  </p>
</main>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Although It seems not working for me, it works well when I used  `p` as css selector for `scroll-margin-top`.

Comment: I've updated it to just select everything `*` for cases where your using javascript or when using the element's name for linking.

Comment: For me, this was the resolution in my Angular app. Great. Never heard of this.

Answer (score 43):

The following code yields a smooth scroll to the top of the element with an offset for fixed header:

```
var topOfElement = document.querySelector('#targetElement').offsetTop - XX;
window.scroll({ top: topOfElement, behavior: "smooth" });
```

Where XX is the height of your fixed header.

Comment: Saved A DAY for me! I was using `mat-card-content` as my scrollable aria with a `mat-toolbar` as my fixed header. I used `ngx-scroll-to` for my scrolling but it didn't work in mobile. However, your solution worked in mobile but not in standalone, whereas the mentioned package worked vice verca. Combined both and Voila! THANKS!

Comment: probably should be the correct/accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for my specific case. Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

**Edit:** Although less compatible (no IE compatibility), `scroll-margin-top` will also solve this, as mentioned in [Arye Eidelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59253905/1268612).

You can solve this with CSS, by applying a `padding-top` and a negative `margin-top` to the elements that you want to scroll to.

#### [Demo](http://work.karlhorky.com/frontend-tricks/anchors-with-fixed-header/index.html)

```js
// For demo only, no JS needed for the solution
document.querySelector('.scroll-to-working-inline').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.working-inline').scrollIntoView();
});

document.querySelector('.scroll-to-working-block').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.working-block').scrollIntoView();
});

document.querySelector('.scroll-to-broken').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.broken').scrollIntoView();
});
```

```css
/* Relevant styles */
.working-inline {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.working-block {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

/* Allow scrolling to the top */
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Only for the demo */
body { margin: 0; }

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

[class^='working'],
[class^='broken'] {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  scroll to...
  <button class="scroll-to-working-inline">working inline element</button>
  <button class="scroll-to-working-block">working block element</button>
  <button class="scroll-to-broken">broken element</button>
</header>

<main>
  <p>Sql daemon epoch all your base are belong to us packet system perl semaphore. Interpreter warez pragma kilo worm back door baz continue chown blob unix Dennis Ritchie stack mutex bar throw fopen man pages linux. Sql suitably small values bit infinite loop pwned rm -rf.</p>
  
  <a class="working-inline">Working inline</a>
  
  <p>Syn baz man pages unix vi crack leapfrog semaphore fail pwned afk null socket cd long leet emacs Donald Knuth bin grep todo pragma stdio.h January 1, 1970. Alloc gc system new finally sql stack trace syn mainframe cat machine code memory leak server salt flood tunnel in back door thread. Bytes fatal throw ctl-c Dennis Ritchie over clock eof tera perl regex.</p>
  
  <div class="working-block">Working block element</div>
  
  <p>Public injection class unix malloc error script kiddies packet less fail int I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that. Tarball memory leak double rsa pwned public all your base are belong to us. False bytes bang bar tarball semaphore warez cd port daemon exception mountain dew sql mainframe gcc ifdef chown private.</p>
  
  <div class="broken">Broken element</div>
  
  <p>Daemon bubble sort protected mutex overflow grep snarf crack warez I'm compiling bit if memory leak Starcraft nak script kiddies long it's a feature. Hello world public server James T. Kirk injection terminal wannabee race condition syn alloc. Gobble leapfrog finally bypass concurrently while irc gurfle do back door blob man pages sql over clock.</p>
  
  <p>Char hello world then man pages ascii long salt while char fatal do boolean tunnel in system else foo packet sniffer float terminal int default. Trojan horse ssh ifdef /dev/null chown cache error protocol afk todo rm -rf mainframe piggyback pwned regex xss warez Starcraft try catch stdio.h bubble sort. It's a feature I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that *.* port bypass ip.</p>
  
  <p>Stdio.h epoch mutex flood wannabee do race condition sql access exception. Bar pragma man pages dereference flush todo highjack while buffer bit nak big-endian syn xss salt for d00dz. Leslie Lamport linux server error hexadecimal snarf tunnel in rm -rf firewall then shell all your base are belong to us.</p>

  <p>Ascii gcc grep int flood kilo linux access mailbomb hash *.* fork semaphore frack else win bar ssh Leslie Lamport. Man pages strlen cache gnu segfault tarball race condition perl packet sniffer root cookie private chown d00dz January 1, 1970. Rsa public crack bit warez throw for void concurrently ip mutex.</p>
  
  <p>Char hello world then man pages ascii long salt while char fatal do boolean tunnel in system else foo packet sniffer float terminal int default. Trojan horse ssh ifdef /dev/null chown cache error protocol afk todo rm -rf mainframe piggyback pwned regex xss warez Starcraft try catch stdio.h bubble sort. It's a feature I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that *.* port bypass ip.</p>
  
  <p>Stdio.h epoch mutex flood wannabee do race condition sql access exception. Bar pragma man pages dereference flush todo highjack while buffer bit nak big-endian syn xss salt for d00dz. Leslie Lamport linux server error hexadecimal snarf tunnel in rm -rf firewall then shell all your base are belong to us.</p>

  <p>Ascii gcc grep int flood kilo linux access mailbomb hash *.* fork semaphore frack else win bar ssh Leslie Lamport. Man pages strlen cache gnu segfault tarball race condition perl packet sniffer root cookie private chown d00dz January 1, 1970. Rsa public crack bit warez throw for void concurrently ip mutex.</p>
  
  <p>Char hello world then man pages ascii long salt while char fatal do boolean tunnel in system else foo packet sniffer float terminal int default. Trojan horse ssh ifdef /dev/null chown cache error protocol afk todo rm -rf mainframe piggyback pwned regex xss warez Starcraft try catch stdio.h bubble sort. It's a feature I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that *.* port bypass ip.</p>
  
  <p>Stdio.h epoch mutex flood wannabee do race condition sql access exception. Bar pragma man pages dereference flush todo highjack while buffer bit nak big-endian syn xss salt for d00dz. Leslie Lamport linux server error hexadecimal snarf tunnel in rm -rf firewall then shell all your base are belong to us.</p>

  <p>Ascii gcc grep int flood kilo linux access mailbomb hash *.* fork semaphore frack else win bar ssh Leslie Lamport. Man pages strlen cache gnu segfault tarball race condition perl packet sniffer root cookie private chown d00dz January 1, 1970. Rsa public crack bit warez throw for void concurrently ip mutex.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Very nice CSS only solution.

Comment: I can't believe it worked so well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 13):

A great simple solution (inspired by Sanyam Jain's comment) is to use `{block: 'center'}` to vertically center the selection like this:

```
scrollIntoView({block: 'center'})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Indeed, that's a clever workaround and turns out to be better than my original requirement.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following. It works well for me:

```
  const headerHeight = 50; /* PUT HEADER HEIGHT HERE */
  const buffer = 25; /* MAY NOT BE NEEDED */
  const scrollToEl = document.querySelector("#YOUR-ELEMENT-SELECTOR");

  const topOfElement = window.pageYOffset + scrollToEl.getBoundingClientRect().top - headerHeight - buffer;
  window.scroll({ top: topOfElement, behavior: "smooth" });
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/wvZMKvq

The header is fixed on top, the orange items in the list are scrolled to a position just below the header. Any other text is the filler to better demonstrate the scrolling. The `scrollItem` is the old way of doing scrolling, one that breaks once the header gets fixed.

```js
let currentItem = 1;

let clickButton = document.getElementById('click-button');
clickButton.addEventListener("click", () =>  {
  alert("clicsk " + currentItem);

  /*scrollItem(currentItem);*/
  
    betterScroll(currentItem);
  currentItem++;
});

let resetButton = document.getElementById('reset-button');
resetButton.addEventListener("click", () =>  {
  currentItem = 1;
 /* scrollItem(currentItem);*/
  betterScroll(currentItem);
 });

function scrollItem(number)  {
  if (number <= 5)  {
    let item = document.getElementById(number);
    alert(item.innerHTML);
    
    item.scrollIntoView();
  
  
  }
}

function betterScroll(number)  {
  if (number <= 5)  {
    alert("betterScroll");
    
    let item = document.getElementById(number);
  
    const headerHeight = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
    alert("header height = " + headerHeight);
    
    const topOfElement = window.pageYOffset + item.getBoundingClientRect().top - headerHeight;
      window.scroll({ top: topOfElement, behavior: "smooth" });
  } 
}
```

```css
#wrapper  {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: flex-start;
}

#header  {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 50px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 1em;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-items: space-between;

 /* position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;*/
position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;
}

.item  {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
}

#click-button, #reset-button  {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

#click-button:hover, #reset-button:hover  {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 70%;
}

#reset-button  {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  
  <div id='header'>
    <div id='click-button'>
      Click to scroll
    </div>
    
    <div id='reset-button'>
      Reset
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris. Sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst. Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla.

Semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Ante in nibh mauris cursus. Morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Hendrerit dolor magna eget est. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta. Ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam.
  </div>
  
  <div id='list'>
    
    <div class='item' id='1'>
      Item 1
    </div>
   <div>
    Neque gravida in fermentum et. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis.


  </div>
  
    
    <div class='item' id='2'>
      Item 2
    </div>
      <div>
    Neque gravida in fermentum et. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis.


  </div>
  
    
    <div class='item' id='3'>
      Item 3
    </div>
      <div>
    Neque gravida in fermentum et. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis.


  </div>
  
    
    <div class='item' id='4'>
      Item 4
    </div>
      <div>
    Neque gravida in fermentum et. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis.


  </div>
  
    
    <div class='item' id='5'>
      Item 5
    </div>
  </div>
    <div>
    Neque gravida in fermentum et. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi. Tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis.


  </div>
  
 
</div>
```

Comment: This works well indeed. I made a codepen, will edit your answer

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone has fixed navbar which hides Header\Title after scrolling, here is the solution (based on `@coco puffs`'s answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441816/4992248)):

```
let anchorLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]')

for (let item of anchorLinks) {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let hashVal = item.getAttribute('href')
    let topOfElement = document.querySelector(hashVal).offsetTop - 70

    window.scroll({ top: topOfElement, behavior: "smooth" })
    history.pushState(null, null, hashVal)
    e.preventDefault()
  })
}
```

In the code `70px` are used.

Comment: I prefer this solution. Works really well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anybody runs into issues with the top margin of your container div being ignored after a scrollIntoView, then instead of scrolling your element into view, just do a scrollTop relative to its parent scrolling container, as such:

```
var topOfElementToView= $('#elementToScroll').position().top;
$('#parentScrollingContainer').scrollTop(topOfElementToView);
```

Got the answer from user113716 on this thread: [How to go to a specific element on page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page)

Comment: Assumes jquery is available.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what will work for the individual will greatly depend on their page layout, so this answer is intended as an additional option rather than to usurp anyone.

All I needed to do was pass false to scroll into view `scrollIntoView(false)`

```
it('should be able to click a button selector', function () {
    let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    let button = element(by.css('.my-button-css));

    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false)', button.getWebElement()).then(function () {
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button), 3000).then(function () {
            expect(button.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
            button.click();

            // more test logic here

        });
    });
});
```

Thanks to [reboot jeff](http://rebootjeff.github.io/blog/2014/08/17/protractor-e2e-testing-reveal-element-blocked-by-fixed-nav/)

Comment: I know this is an older thread but this the only solution that worked for me with a fixed header. As per the MDN using element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"}); is equivalent to using false but offers a smoother scroll.

Answer (score 0):

For me scrolling the element into the center of the window would have worked.

`scrollIntoViewIfNeeded({ block: "center" })` does this nicely but unfortunately only has limited browser compatibility (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded). It does not work on IE and Firefox.

You can, however, build this function pretty easily yourself:

```
function scrollIntoCenter(element) {
  // first scroll element into view. This means element is at the very top.
  element.scrollIntoView();
  
  // calculate new scrollYPosition by subtracting half of window-height
  let y = window.scrollY - window.innerHeight/2;
  
  // scroll up by half of window height
  window.scroll(0, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```js
var messageContainer
var message
var autoScroll

var messageCounter = 0
var messageQuantity = 20
while(messageQuantity >1){
        messageQuantity--
        messageContainer = document.createElement('div')
        messageContainer.className = 'messageContainer'

        message = document.createElement('div')
        message.className = 'message'

        message.innerHTML = `message: ${messageCounter++}`
        messageContainer.append(message)

        document.getElementsByClassName('overflow_section')[0].append(messageContainer)
        
        document.getElementById('messageQuantity').textContent = `counter: ${messageCounter}`
}

var appendMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('appendMessage')[0]
        appendMessage.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            autoScroll = document.getElementById('autoScroll')
                    
            messageContainer = document.createElement('div')
            messageContainer.className = 'messageContainer'
            
            message = document.createElement('div')
            message.className = 'message'
        
            message.innerHTML = `message: ${messageCounter++}`
            messageContainer.append(message)
            
            document.getElementsByClassName('overflow_section')[0].append(messageContainer)
            
            if(autoScroll.checked){
                var count = document.getElementsByClassName('overflow_section')[0].getElementsByClassName('messageContainer')
                document.getElementsByClassName('messageContainer')[count.length - 1].scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' 
                })
            }
            document.getElementById('messageQuantity').textContent = `counter: ${messageCounter}`
                
        })
        
        var scrollUp = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollUp')[0]       
        scrollUp.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            var count = document.getElementsByClassName('overflow_section')[0].getElementsByClassName('messageContainer')   
                if(count.length > 0){
                   document.getElementsByClassName('messageContainer')[0].scrollIntoView({
                        behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'start' 
                    })  
                }           
                        
        })
        
        var scrollDown = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollDown')[0]       
        scrollDown.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            var count = document.getElementsByClassName('overflow_section')[0].getElementsByClassName('messageContainer')   
                if(count.length > 0){
                     document.getElementsByClassName('messageContainer')[count.length - 1].scrollIntoView({
                        behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' 
                    })
                }           
                            
        })
```

```css
button{
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    border:none;
    color:white;
}

input{
   background-color: rgb(179 229 249 / 50%);
   position:relative;
   top:10px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}

.overflow_section{
    overflow: auto;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color: rgb(179 229 249 / 50%);
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    margin:15px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.messageContainer{
    background-color: rgb(255 120 0 / 50%);
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:15px;
}


#messageQuantity{
    background-color: rgb(255 120 0 / 100%);
    font-weight:700;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
    <span align="center" id='messageQuantity'></span>
    <button class='appendMessage'>Append message</button>
    <button class='scrollUp'>Scroll Up</button>
    <button class='scrollDown'>Scroll Down</button>

    <input type="checkbox" id="autoScroll" />
    <label for="vehicle1">Auto scroll</label>
</div>
<div class='overflow_section'></div>
```