# Position: Fixed not working with scrollIntoView()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search bar at the top of a navigable table, which I want the position to be fixed so it is still visible while scrolling. The table puts itself over the search bar. I use scrollIntoView() in the table navigation script to move the view to the selected row. Here is a jsfiddle with the problem occuring: https://jsfiddle.net/5umztjty/

```css
#screen {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 110;
    width: 255px;
    height: 140px;
    
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#pokemons-list {
    padding-top: 3px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    align-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#mySearch {
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

I also tried this fix [Using scrollIntoView with a fixed position header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614112/using-scrollintoview-with-a-fixed-position-header)

But it's still not working. In this case the selected element is a table row, so I have :

```js
var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").children[1].children; 
var selectedRow
var yourHeight = '20px';
```

so I wrote

```js
// scroll to your element 
rows[selectedRow].scrollIntoView(true); 

// now account for fixed header 
var scrolledY = window.scrollY; if(scrolledY) { 

window.scroll(0, scrolledY - yourHeight); 

}
```

I didn't put the navigation script but it works well (at the beginning the var selectedRow value is 0)

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with the top, left, and right (I exclude bottom since you mentioned that you want the search bar at the top) properties of `position: fixed;` for instance:

`#mySearch {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}`

Comment: Thank you, the search bar is fixed now, but the table puts itself over the search bar, what would be the simpliest solution to fix this please ?

Comment: @Nas You need to indicate which elements should be in front or behind of other elements. For this you simply need to adjust the [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Here's an old post with that exact issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614112/using-scrollintoview-with-a-fixed-position-header

Comment: sorry I misexplained I said something completely false in the deleted comment it's not that the z-index is ignored but my table content is showed in the background of the search bar. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Nas No worries. Did you see check out the link that I shared a few minutes ago?

Comment: I tried the fix in the link you shared me but I don't know why it's not working for me, I added what I've done in my code in the post. Any idea why it is not working ??

Answer (score 0):

Add a `left` and `top` position to the `#mySearch`. For example:

```
#mySearch {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3px;
    left: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the search bar is fixed now, but the table puts itself over the search bar, how can I fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Height of the body is for you can scroll down
Use the Fix to fix position of your search bar, then give your body content a margin-top.  You can set value of the margin-top to show all infor you want to show in body.

```css
body{
    height: 200Vh;
}

#screen {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#pokemons-list {
 margin-top: 4vh;
}

#mySearch {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="screen">

      <input id='mySearch' onkeyup='searchPokemon()' type='text' autocomplete="off">

      <table id="pokemons-list">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>NO</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <!--auto-generated-->
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Name1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Name2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Name3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Name4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Name5</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but it's not working in my case, here is a jsfiddle which exactly shows my problem: