# scrollintoview() blocked by sticky Navbar

Tags: javascript, html

For some unknown reason to me, my navigation bar is blocking the div content.

Below is my example code. How can I fix it so the `div` wouldn't be blocked by the sticky navigation bar when I click the button?

```html
<div style="height:90px; border: 1px solid red; background-color: grey; position: fixed; width: 100%;">Navbar</div>

<div id="A">
This text will blocked by sticky navbar
<br/>A<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>---
</div>

<div id="B">
This text will blocked by sticky navbar
<br/>B<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>---
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<button onClick="document.getElementById('A').scrollIntoView();">A</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById('B').scrollIntoView();">B</button>
```

Comment: This might help you --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614112/using-scrollintoview-with-a-fixed-position-header

Comment: Is there any ways for me to write the script inside onClick command?

Comment: In the answer they provided a link, which scrolls when the button is clicked --> https://work.karlhorky.com/frontend-tricks/anchors-with-fixed-header/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using scrollIntoView with a fixed position header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614112/using-scrollintoview-with-a-fixed-position-header)

Comment: so I have to re-structure all my script I've write? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leave some pixels from top so that the content will appear to start from the bottom of navbar. In this case `padding-bottom` worked.

```js
function scrollToView(id){
  var top = document.getElementById(id).offsetTop-document.getElementById("nav").offsetHeight-10;
  //show 10 pixels down the border
  window.scrollTo(0, top);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:90px; border: 1px solid red; background-color: grey; position: fixed; width: 100%;" id="nav">Navbar</div>

<div id="A" style="padding-top: 100px">
This text will blocked by sticky navbar
<br/>A<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>---
</div>

<div id="B">
This text will blocked by sticky navbar
<br/>B<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>---
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="C">
This text will blocked by sticky navbar
<br/>C<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>---
</div>

<button onClick="scrollToView('A')">A</button>
<button onClick="scrollToView('B')">B</button>
```

Comment: its not about the padding. what i need is to put every targeted div just bellow the navbar.

Comment: I did.. And I'm pretty much understand the changes, but its not what it needs.. The padding 100px will ruin gaps above it..