# Table of Contents - Anchors hash links not working

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="toc-container" class="no-bullets">
    <span class="toc-title">Contents</span>
    <ul class="toc-list">
        <li><a href="#lorem-ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h2><span id="lorem-ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</span></h2>
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
var link = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++)
{
    link[i].onclick = function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var b = this;
        var c = b.getAttribute("href").substring(1);
        var el = document.querySelectorAll('span[id="'+c+'"]')[0];
        window.scrollTo({top:el.offsetTop -1,behavior:"smooth"});
    };
}
```

When click the link, it works perfectly but hash *#lorem-ipsum* not showing in the address bar like this: example.com/post-title#Lorem-Ipsum So how do we solve that?

Please note that I don't want to use any jQuery plugin. As I couldn't solve the problem permanently, I asked over here and my expectation is that this problem will be solved.

Comment: the url address bar is not updated because you call preventDefault and do not actually navigate to a new url, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History, in particular pushState and replaceState

Comment: @mattrichards Well, if I remove preventDefault or replace it with stopPropagation, works like a charm but then smooth scroll won't work...

Comment: after your window.scrollTo call, add window.location='#'+c, you can use the history api as well, this will add an entry to the browsers history, if you dont want that use window.history.replaceState({},'','#'+c);

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work but thank you. I've found another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51485162