# auto-scroll grid in jqm

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, grid

I have a simple webapp consisting of a main page that contains a grid with 3 columns.

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-b" id="main">
    </div>
</div>
```

At runtime this grid is expanded with new rows by clicking a button.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page-home', function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var table = $('#main');
        var blocka = $('<div class="ui-block-a">One</div>');
        var blockb = $('<div class="ui-block-b">Two</div>');
        var blockc = $('<div class="ui-block-c">Three</div>');
        blocka.appendTo(table);
        blockb.appendTo(table);
        blockc.appendTo(table);
    });
});
```

Now I have the problem that if there are more rows added (let's say 10) then the last rows run out of screen.
Is there a simple way to automatically scroll to the last row everytime a new one is created?
I know that I can get the element by calling table.find('.ui-block-a:last') but I don't know how to scroll to the found element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in this answer: [How to go to a specific element on page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page)

Add the following after blockc.appendTo(table) in your click handler:

```
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: blocka.offset().top + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
```

Here is fiddle demo:  **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5ap48/**