# WebBrowser scroll to tr

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser-Control where I load a HTML-Document. In the HTML-Document there are several entries like `<tr class="uierror">`.

To get the content of the WebBrowser I use:

```
if(webBrowser.Document != null)
{
   mshtml.HTMLDocument htmlDocument = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
   if(htmlDocument != null)
   {

   }
}
```

But now I have no idea how to scroll to the first occurence of `<tr class="uierror">`. How can I do this?

Ok. I've managed it to get the IHTMLElement to the `<tr class="uierror">` with

```
IHTMLElementCollection elements = htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("tr");
foreach(IHTMLElement element in elements)
{
   if(element.className == "uierror")
   {

   }
}
```

Now how can I scroll to this position?

Comment: I think Javascript can give you a solution, check following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page

Comment: And how can I execute a javascript to my webBrowser-Control in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I managed it. The IHTMLElement has a method `scrollIntoView`. That's it.