# anchor links issues | Works in firefox but not chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, anchor

I am redesigning my site and I'm have a basic but annoying issue with my anchor links.

Site is here http://cdechmedia.com/WIP/

as you can see I'm using a fix navigation bar and my goal is to make it that when ever someone presses the nav link it will go to that section of course :)

Here is were the issue comes in. I have set my anchor in a div so I could position it in correctly so that when they select lets say contact us it wont be cut off by the navigation. Now it works perfectly in Firefox but not in chrome. HELP!!!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to that [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page) it's a simple plugin to scroll to html element.

Comment: is there anyway to fix this without jquery or javascript?

Comment: You can do it only with JavaScript and CSS but at least JavaScript for apply the CSS classes that make the navigation between the elements.

Comment: sigh guess i need to start learning more java because I have no idea what its telling me to do. looks like that's the answer for the bbq plugin and not just for basic anchors.