# pixel offset(x,y) of the start and end of the string in webview

Tags: javascript, dom, android-webview

I have a webview in which am loading an xhtml.
I have a string in the page, say "Machine Head" which is unique, i.e., it is the only word which is present.
I need to find the offset(pixel) of that string using javascript so that I can scroll accordingly.
Am not able to find a function that will take String as an input and return the pixel offset of the position from where the string begins.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function. Can you add an anchor and navigate to it instead? So add `<a href='#machine_head' />` in your page and call `webView.loadUrl("http://....html#machine_head");`? Alternavively you could try using JavaScript to scroll to the right element as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page).