# AngularJS : Why the data is not displayed in view may I use $scope.apply?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting data from service and display on view using **ng-repeat** .Actually I am getting event when user scroll to bottom mean when user reached to bottom I will do something.When It reached to bottom I am changing the contend of my array .I am getting the correct contend in ng-repeat array (display array) but it is not reflect on view why ? May I use **$scope.apply() or $scope.digest()**

Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/XgOxJnPXZk4DneJonlKV?p=preview

Here I am changing the contend of my display array which is not reflect on view

```
if (container[0].offsetHeight + container[0].scrollTop >= container[0].scrollHeight) {
            if(scope.var<scope.arrays.length)
            scope.display=[];
            var nextvar =++counter;
            var increment=counter+1
            console.log("nextvar:"+nextvar+"increment:"+increment)
            scope.display=scope.arrays[nextvar].concat(scope.arrays[increment]);
           console.log(scope.display)
          }
```

Comment: yes, in this case you do need to use `scope.$apply()`, because you are actually replacing the `display` array with a new array, so the old listeners on `display` are no longer valid.  however, once that's resolved, you have the issue of your counter being reset every pass through the loop, leaving you only able to scroll down once...

Comment: could you please give plunker

Comment: how I will slove this issue ? could you please explain more and solve my issues

Comment: yes I check the value of variable become same how I make static variable @Claies please give better anser

Comment: I never intended to provide an answer, only a comment that might alert you to the fact that you have larger issues in your code

Comment: But you should provide one better solution to others

Comment: I **don't** have a solution! I merely offered a comment, I never committed to providing an answer.

Comment: it ok I got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Claies mentioned you should use apply(). Though the digest() would probably have worked as well.apply() calls digest() internally. He also mentioned that your variable that seems to be storing the page number gets reset to 0 each time you scroll. You should store that in a scope variable outside that handler. 
I tried to fix with minimum change

http://plnkr.co/edit/izV3Dd7raviCt4j7C8wu?p=preview

```
 .directive("scrollable", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var container = angular.element(element);
      container.bind("scroll", function(evt) {
        console.log('scroll called'+container[0].scrollTop);
        var counter = scope.page;
        if (container[0].scrollTop <= 0) {
          if (scope.var > 0)
            scope.display = scope.arrays[--scope.var].concat(scope.arrays[scope.var+1]);

        }

        if (container[0].offsetHeight + container[0].scrollTop >= container[0].scrollHeight) {

          if (scope.var < scope.arrays.length)
            scope.display = [];
          var nextvar = ++counter;
          var increment = counter + 1
          console.log("nextvar:" + nextvar + "increment:" + increment)
          scope.display = scope.arrays[nextvar].concat(scope.arrays[increment]);
          console.log(scope.display)
          scope.page = counter;
        }
        scope.$apply();
      });
    };
  })
```

generally I would have implemented this differently. For example by having a spinning wheel on the bottom of the list that when displayed you get the rest of data. 
It is difficult to give you a full working plunker. Probably you should have multiple JSON files in the plunker, each containing the data for one page so that we can add the data to the bottom of the display list.

Comment: great  answer ...!! Actually My motive is to load data when user scroll to bottom ..your answer is correct  but still it is issue.Issue is  user not recognise that we are change data .In other word issue of scroll position .scroll position move to top when we load data

Comment: Scroll position remain at that point where we load data...Example  we are on "L" when new data load ..But when we load more data  it goes to "R".it remain on "L" when I load more data .so that it look like we are not loading new data

Comment: can we maintain the scroll position ? In other words when user scoll to bottom it load data more .But I need scroll position remain same when it was previous or before loading

Comment: I will try this first.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page

Comment: did you have any answer .if yes please post your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752982/why-scroll-position-goes-to-bottom-when-new-data-load

Comment: But you did it using jquery I need for angularjs

Comment: You can scroll to any element using the above sample, but in AngularJS where you don't know what that element would be it is not that easy

Comment: @brain what is best way to load huge data like 2000 element ..Without using pagination.Actually in mobile my app become slow.That why I am searching to load and remove data from dom concept

Comment: I think I understand your question which is like this: While the volume of data is easy to load from network or file, we don't want to create all dom elements to avoid slowness. how can we dynamically add/remove them to dom as the user scrolls in an AngularJS project? I would implement that as a 'pull to refresh' from bottom and top. I have not done it in AngularJS before but apparently someone has created this plugin https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-pull-to-refresh

Comment: Maybe put this specifically as a Question in stack overflow to get a better answer. This question you have created is focused on $scope.$apply() and now that you have sorted that out, you can focus on your performance issue.

Comment: Also remember if performance becomes a major issue for your mobile app, maybe consider not using Angular. The Angular compile and controller overhead is sometimes too much for some apps

Answer (score 0):

After you modify `display` array you just have to call `scope.$apply()` so that it runs the `$digest` cycle and updates the view. Also you need the initialize `scope.var` either in your controller or the directive and modify it conditionally.

I dont if this is what you want. I have modified the plunker take a look.
http://plnkr.co/edit/J89VDMQGIXvFnK86JUxx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for answer ..But there is a issue what @claie said ..when I scroll to bottom it change my array using scope .apply .But when again I scroll my nextvar and increment value not change why

Comment: why when I scroll again why my variable not show 2, 3 value o f nextvar ,increment .I need to load more data when user scroll to bottom

Comment: how to change counter variable ..? mean I need to change counter variable when user scroll to top and bottom