# Index of li in ul but using D3, not Jquery

Tags: d3.js, html-lists

Very similar to other Jquery questions, but I cannot get around how to accomplish the same with pure d3 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to understanding how D3 selections work. Whenever you're dealing with a selection and provide a function to be consumed you've got a standard set of parameters. All this is available in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each):

- `d` is the **datum** parameter which represents the data bound to that element
- `i` is the **index** parameter, this is the bit you're after!

`this` is also redefined, such it represents the DOM element that you are dealing with.

So an example would be:

```
d3.selectAll("li")
  .each(function(d, i) { 
      console.log("This <li> tag " + i);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The after I get the index, is it possible to use d3.select(ul).properties("ScrollTo",index) to move the scroller

Comment: @LoredraL that's a separate question really. However, as mentioned `this` is the actual element, so if you know which of those particular elements you want to scroll to, then you could pass `this` into a function like demonstrated in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page . The important part being `$(this).offset().top + 'px'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
d3.selectAll('li')
    .attr('color',function(d,i){
        console.log(this,i);
    })
```

I've made a fiddle which in console you can see the index.

http://jsfiddle.net/a2QpA/294/