# Force scroll on a specific url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve an effect/redirect on a website I'm developing for my company.

Previously we have had a `mydomain.com/weather`, direct to a specific page showing the weather. Now, since we moved the weather to a section of the root page (`/`), we want the users who go to `mydomain.com/weather` to land on the root page but with the window scrolled to the weather section.

Essentially, i'm trying to achieve the same effect of a same page anchor (`#myAnchor`) but with a url.

I've searched on Google for same page anchor url slash but I only could find stuff regarding the regular anchors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the desired result using a combination of the answer above and `window.pathname`
essentially:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if(window.pathname == '/weather') {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#weather-area').offset().top
      }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, give your "weather" section an id

```
<div id="weather">
    <!-- weather content -->
</div>
```

Voila! Visit `mydomain.com/#weather` now. The browser should scroll you to corresponding element. This also applied to anchor tag

```
<a href="#weather">Weather</a>
```

#### Implementing animation

Suppose you're going to apply scroll animation when certain element clicked

```
<a class="to-weather" href="javascript:void(0);">See weather here</a>
<button type="button" class="to-weather">See weather here</button>
```

with jQuery

```
$('.to-weather').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#weather").offset().top
    }, slow);
});
```

---

### Redirect

Either .htaccess and PHP both can handle redirection

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^weather$ /#weather$ [R=301,NE,L]
```

PHP

```
header("Location: /#weather", true, 301);
```

#### Implementing animation

A hacky solution but works. First, Set the `#weather` on element on topper area of document such as `body`

```
<body id="weather">
```

Browser will stayed at top as the id its bound to is on body tag. And once document is ready, you can do scrolling animation to desired element with just a simple validation. I'll name it `#weather-area`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Not all browser contains # in location.hash
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if(hash === 'weather') {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#weather-area').offset().top
      }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: This I know, what I'm trying to achieve is the exact opposite: enter mysite.com/weather (notice the missing #) and have page load and scroll to that section. I've read somewhere that it can be done with rewrite rules (the website already has some defined for it).

Comment: I thought you said, you already knew how to redirect and just want to get to know how to scroll on specific element. I've updated my answer. @ddrjm

Comment: Hey again. I was wondering, is there any way I can get rid of the hash? I want to go to /weather and not /#weather