# How to scroll to bottom with a button click/addEventListener in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

Okey i got three iframes, and i want to have a button so i can immediately scroll to button of one of the iframe(iframe1). I think i got most of the code correct, i just dont know how to make the 'function scrollDown'

My code:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://examplepage1.com"><iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" src="http://examplepage2.com"><iframe>
<iframe id="iframe3" src="http://examplepage3.com"><iframe>

<button id="scroll">Go to button</button>


<script>

var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll");

scroll.addEventListener("click", scrollDown);

function scrollDown() {

    }
```

Comment: take a look on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

> 1. scrollIntoView() :The scrollIntoView() method scrolls the specified
>      element into the visible  area of the browser window. 
>              e.g. var element = document.getElementById("bottomDiv");
>              element.scrollIntoView()
> 2. scrollTo() :Scrolls the document to the specified coordinates
>                 eg. window.scrollTo(0,0).
> 3. scroll() :Scrolls the window to a particular place in the document.
>                 window.scroll(x-coord, y-coord) 
>                 e.g. scroll(0, 100)