# scroll to specific element on mobile phone doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a click event which I want when is fired, window scroll to the specific coordinates

```
<div class="col-xs-12 responsiveView">
<div class="row" id="selectedDay"></div>
<div class="responsiveOrders"></div>
<div class="responsiveNewOrders row">
    <div class="orderMenuTitle">

    </div>
</div>
```

,so far I have used the codes below in reference to the [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) and [How to go to a specific element on page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801655/how-to-go-to-a-specific-element-on-page)

```
$('html').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".responsiveView").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

and

```
var x = $('.responsiveView').offset().left;
var y = $('.responsiveView').offset().top;
window.scrollTo(x,y);
```

animate works fine on browser's responsive view but **none of them works on an actual iphone**.
I have searched a lot and this is not a duplicate!
your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: I believe if you are using a click event listener, a mobile device will not register that because mobile devices use on touch events.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: the click event works because ajax is sent and data is displayed, the problem is scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same approach

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".responsiveView").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

and it worked, the problem was that I tried to scroll the page before the specific box (element with responsiveView class) was fully loaded, so I put the above code on the callback of my function (when data was loaded and box was fully visible) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might work for some people but if doesn't work for you can use `setTimeOut()` to execute the function.

```
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('html').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".responsiveView").offset().top
     }, 1000)
   }, 100);
```