# Simple Scroll to ID not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

`<div id="scrolltotabs"></div>`

`<a href="#scrolltotabs">SCROLL</a>`

When clicking on SCROLL, the screen should scroll to the respective ID. It works totally fine on Desktop, but id doesn't work on mobile. Does anyone know any fix for this?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844300/scroll-to-specific-element-on-mobile-phone-doesnt-work

Comment: Is it working on the mobile screen simulator in the inspecting tool?

Comment: No, it is not working on the inspecting tool either. Any way to do it without jQuery?

Comment: Can you upload your code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io) or any online development environment, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple css so it will work perfectly.

```html
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```