# possible to use jquery to skip to a certain part of a page, based on its div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a link that scrolls the page to the start of the `<div class="content-body">`

The same functionality as a: `<a href="#maincontent">Skip</a>`, and placing `<a name="maincontent"></a>` right next to `<div class="content-body">`

I am seeing if it is possible via jQuery, and want to know if I would run into any problems down the road using that method (besides the user having javascript disabled).

Comment: Something like this? [$.scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in all browsers and no need for $.scrollTo plugin. Just make a link with `<a href="#content-body">` and it will go to the correct spot.

```
$('a[href="#content-body"]').click(function(){
    $('html,body').scrollTop( $('.content-body').offset().top );
    return false;
});
```

If you want to animate the scrolling do this. (You can replace 500 with whatever speed you want the animation to be at)

```
$('a[href="#content-body"]').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.content-body').offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Since you are using a class to select the element, there might be more than one DOM node with class 'content-body'. This will scroll to the first one. If you want to scroll to the n-th one do this. (You can replace n with which ever numbered element you want)

```
$('a[href="#content-body"]').click(function(){
    $('html,body').scrollTop( $('.content-body').eq(n).offset().top );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You should add `return false;` or `evt.stopPropagation();` in your click callbacks to prevent the anchor from actually going to the matching id (if there is one).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you check out the [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin. Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruxwn/) example on jsFiddle.

**Edit**
The key here is to use the `.offset().top` as the position to scroll to. This is the top of the element relative to the document (versus `.position().top` which would be relative to it's parent positioned container). You can also use the [built-in function](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) `.scrollTop(value)` if you don't want the scroll to be animated or you don't want to use the plug-in.

**Edit 2**
Also, note you can use any selector you want for this part: `$('div:nth-child(1)').offset().top` In your case you'd want `$('div.content-body').offset().top`. Just remember that `.offset()` only returns the position of the first matched element.

**Example**
*HTML*

```
<div id="first" style="background:red;">
    <a href="#" class="go1">First</a>
    <a href="#" class="go2">Second</a>
    <a href="#" class="go3">Third</a>
</div>
<div id="second" style="background:blue;">
    <a href="#" class="go1">First</a>
    <a href="#" class="go2">Second</a>
    <a href="#" class="go3">Third</a>
</div>
<div id="second" style="background:green;">
    <a href="#" class="go1">First</a>
    <a href="#" class="go2">Second</a>
    <a href="#" class="go3">Third</a>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
div {
    height:1000px;
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
$(function() {
    $('.go1').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($('div:nth-child(1)').offset().top, 500);
        return false;
    });
    $('.go2').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($('div:nth-child(2)').offset().top, 500);
        return false;
    });
    $('.go3').click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($('div:nth-child(3)').offset().top, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```