# targeting nex div within each function

Tags: jquery

I have like the following html:

```
<div id="mainbar">
    <div class="swrap sliderwrap-1"></div>
    <div class="swrap sliderwrap-2"></div>
    <div class="swrap sliderwrap-3"></div>
    <div class="swrap sliderwrap-4"></div>
</div>
```

And I wanted to **hide** (to illustrate here only) when the red div bottom offset is about to black fixed div so I'm targeting current's next div offset so that it's bottom offset would get and when scrolling upto this offset value the red div box should be hidden and again if scrolled to green div's bottom offset then the green div box should be hidden. I have tried a lot but too much confused how can I do?

jQuery:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $('.swrap').each(function(){
        var s = $(window).scrollTop();
        var t = $(this).next().offset().top ;
        if(s>t) $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8y4U/)

But it's not working as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when a DIV is hidden it issues a window resize which also issues a scrool... Since the next div in line will then be placed above the point where it should be removed, then it is removed.

Check this example where I resized the DIVs so that when the first one is deleted, the next is still large enough to remain below the non-delete area:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MuT6u/)

```
.sliderwrap-1{
    height: 20%;
    background: #f00;
}
.sliderwrap-2{
    height: 40%;
    background: #0f0;
}
.sliderwrap-3{
    height: 60%;
    background: #ff0;
}
.sliderwrap-4{
    height: 120%;
    background: #f0f;
}
```

On top of that I also think you are miscalculating the point where the DIV should be hidden. It only happens when the top of the next DIV leaves the screen and not when the top of the next DIV goes under the black area.

What can be done? It will be too much to show it all here but I would suggest that before you enter the code to hide the DIV you do the following steps:

- [unbind the "on scrool" event](http://jsfiddle.net/VfJhd/4/)
- hide the DIV to be hidden
- [reposition the top of the next DIV at the exact same place it was placed before hiding the previous DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery)
- [re-bind the "on scrool" event](http://jsfiddle.net/VfJhd/4/)