# using #last with <a id="last"> make display lower than the top of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this HTML Code on my webpage:

```
<a id="last"></a>
```

however i am also including (PHP) a fixed/static (`style="position:fixed;"`) menu bar at the top of the page so when i go to

`http://www.domain.com/index.php#last`

the `a id` is showing behind the menu bar.

Is there a way I can make it display a little lower down rather than right at the top of the page so it doesn't show behind the menu bar?

Comment: please provide more html and css

Comment: thats all i have in my HTML

Comment: You can just use top: 20px; //pixel value that works.

Comment: Try to read this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery

Comment: Try to read this, problably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery

Comment: Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use some Jquery to move the screen to the point that you want:

```
$("html, body").animate(
{
    scrollTop: $("#last").top + 50
}, 500);
```

Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Sorry, i undertood yout question wrong.

To fix it you should use some CSS, you could use z-index on your a element or some margin.