# LiquidSlider 2: how to properly use crosslinks and share specific slides?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, redirect

I'm using LiquidSlider 2 on my website to slide between WordPress posts. I have something like this (some irrelevant code to this question is ommited):

```
<div class="liquid-slider" id="slider-id">
<?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
echo '<div id="slide'.get_the_ID().'">';
```

And I'm setting up LiquidSlider like this:

```
$('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
                    hoverArrows: false,
                    crossLinks: true,
                    hashLinking: true,
                    hashNames: true,
                    hashTitleSelector: "div.id",
                    hashCrossLinks: true
                }
            );
```

Now I need to do two different things. First, inside each post I have multiple tabs and in one of them the user is able to log in. When the user logs in, he's redirected to a member only area, which has a slider with the same posts but different formatting and more options. The ID of the slider and the ID of the slides is the same of the one in the public page:

```
<div class="liquid-slider" id="slider-id">
<div id='slide".get_the_ID()."'>
```

I want the user, after logging in, to be redirect not only to the member area, but also to that specific post where he logged in. For example, if he logs in on post with ID=40 in the main page, the member page loads the slide with ID=40 first. I went through LiquidSlider2 documentation but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

The second problem is getting a link to share a specific slide. I'm using AddThis to share posts through the social networks. I want that when the user clicks on the link that was shared, he's redirected to that specific slider at that specific position (I have three sliders with different IDs on the same page). I have no idea how to achieve this. When I try putting in the address bar something like http://standcardeira.com/leiloes#2 for example it reloads the page and the first post to appear in the first slider is the second one (the other two sliders remain at position 1). That would be a solution if the page automatically scrolled down to the area containing the posts, but it doesn't, even if I try something like http://standcardeira.com/leiloes#viaturas-content-area.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is scrolling down to the slider area? You can just add some javascript to scroll down to the slider container, #slider-id-wrapper

Check this post out:

[How can I scroll to a specific location on the page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery)

Let me know if that helps. sorry for the late reply.

EDIT:
You can use the API to set the slider to a specific tab location:

```
var api = $.data( $('#main-slider')[0], 'liquidSlider');
api.setNextPanel(3);
```

Using the api, you can also check the current slide location before the user logs in, send it across and access on the new page.

Another options is hashlinking, which can be [found here](http://liquidslider.com/documentation/#externalcontrols-options).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, I have a slider on PAGE A (public page) and another on PAGE B (member area). Each slider has the exact same posts and the same ID for each slide (I use the wordpress post ID to achieve this: for example, if the post has the ID=45, the slide has the ID=slide45). What I want is when the user logs in on, for instance, SLIDE45 on PAGE A, he's redirect to that same SLIDE45 but on PAGE B. It's just a matter of passing the information of the ID of the slide where he logged in so that LiquidSlider knows what post to present first once he's redirected to the member area.