# Spring MVC and JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP page containing several divs.Is it possible to redirect using model and view from Spring to a specific div on the JSP since each of the div's represents a subpage?

```
    <div id="page1" class="content">
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12">
      <div class="slider_wrapper">
        <ul class="items">
          <li> <img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="">
            <div class="caption banner">
              <h2>Let Us Show You the Way to Success</h2>
            </div>
          </li>      
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="socials"> <a href="#"></a> <a href="#"></a> <a href="#"></a> <a href="#"></a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="content">
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12">
      <div class="slogan">
        <h3>Only Professional <a onClick="goToByScroll('page3'); return false;" href="#"><span>Services</span></a> for Our <a onClick="goToByScroll('page4'); return false;" href="#"><em>Clients</em></a></h3>
        <div class="text1"> <a href="#" class="tm_link"> Click here</a> for more info about this free website template created by TemplateMonster.com <br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In mollis erat mattis neque facilisis, sit amet ultricies </div>
      </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would do you mean by "redirect using model and view from Spring to a specific div" ? Just scrolling the page so that the requested view comes at top ?

Comment: Yeah I want the page to be automatically scrolled to a specific div.

Comment: For scrolling you will have to append html anchors in the url like #container_12 and your page will automatically be scrolled to that div by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can imagine is to add an attribute in your model to contain the name of the div to scroll to eg `model.setAttribute("scroll_to", "socials")`. Then in your JSP, you just have to add a piece of javascript to do the actual scroll. As a special case, if the attribute is not present, you simply do not add the javascript.

You will find details on how to scroll using javascript on the following SO posts : [How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript) (generalist) and [How can I scroll to a specific location on the page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery) (jquery specific)