# How to center browser screen in webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page width large size

examble : width:3000px - height: 3000px;

in my page, have a div container and some elements as p, img, button.

I want each time access this page by any browsers, browser screen always center on content of webpage.

you can see picture below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _browser screen_ ?

Comment: Do you want to center your content to your screen? If so: just do `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: You mean Content of the page will center the Browser Screen...? if it is Browser screen will always center to the content. what is the Purpose? please explain

Comment: No, i want browser always scroll to center of content when page load. And Ketan's answer exactly what i want. because i want to make a page like a wall, on the page have some pictures everywhere, users can use mouse to scroll and see these pictures. So i need browser always scroll to center at begin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Following what you want. It will center vertical and horizontal of the screen.

```js
$(function () {
    scrollTo((($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2),(($(document).height() - $(window).height()) / 2));
});
```

```css
.main{
    width:1200px;
    height:1200px;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}

.sub{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub"><h2>I am center</h2></div>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fhj5zvam/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you very much, i will make this is answer. I don't think it very simple like this :((.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the browser to scroll to the center if its too large for the screen and not be at the top-left of the page.

use `scrollIntoView()` in your script after page load

```
document.getElementById("#theDivInTheCenter").scrollIntoView()
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery) question

Comment: Your answer also can solve my problem, but ketan's answer suitable for me.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the purpose, but you can manage that by using absolute positioning:

```
div {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 3000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1500px; /* 50% of the height */
    left 50%;
    margin-left: -1500px; /* 50% of the width */
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: my purpose if, i want to display a page like a wall, on the wall have some picture and users can scrolling page by mouse to see pictures. I will try your code and reply you later, anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
.section{
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    left:25%;
    top: 25%;
}
```

You can try below link to Fiddle to achieve the same:

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/h4y0y5bj/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help but my mean is not this.