# Scroll to element if it not in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, viewport, jquery-jscrollpane

[jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) library have a `scrollToElement` method which can scroll to element if it not in viewport.

Also this method have a `stickToTop` parameter which scroll as little as possible to show the element (not top of the viewport, like it do `scrollTop`).

Anyone knows standalone plugin for that functionality? Or how it can be realised in JS (I'm not an expert in JS and I can't extract this function from jScrollPane).

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: There is a native js method for that but without any kind of animation: [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)   `Anyone knows standalone plugin for that functionality?` That kind of question doesn't fit SO rules...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scroll to a specific location on the page using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery)

Comment: @A.Wolff  actually, scrollIntoView() can be animated (look at scrollIntoViewOptions param at your own MDN link). And for browser with no support of scroll behavior there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll)

Comment: @PaulKozlovitch Ya but that's a working draft, only currently supported on FF BUT good point  EDIT: oops, I didn't have checked your polyfill link... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yuu should user `scrollIntoView(true)` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView