# How do I scroll past the top or bottom of a list in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react component that is generating a list. For examples sake lets say that it looks like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          {...}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {/* These are being generated so there are a bunch*/}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

However I want the list to function in a way that the active list item always falls in the center of the screen. This is not too much of a problem except for when I get to the top or the bottom of the list. I need a way to scroll past the top or the bottom of the list and I am not quite too sure how to do this.

The first idea I had was to create some empty table rows to fill the space needed to scroll up past the top or down past the bottom, but this felt like a "hacky" solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use JQuery to scroll to the element. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery

Comment: That's one way to do it: Add one `tr` to the top and one to the bottom and set the height of it's child `td` to be half the height of the screen minus half the height of the first or last `td`. Or you can just pad the top or the bottom the first or last row, respectively.

Comment: @Aziz I am aiming to not use JQuery if possible. I should have mentioned this in the original post. What would be your backup plan? I cant quite get the ReactDOM to function the way I would like.

Comment: @Adam If you look at the SO answer there is a way to do it using plain javascript via window.location.hash