# Automatic scrolled into view of focus input

Tags: javascript, android, html, forms, google-chrome

How to enable automatic scroll to focus input when keyboard are open ?
I create a [simple demo](http://codepen.io/kholiavko-roman/full/VmJrBR/) where are 2 inputs:

```
<div style="height:300px;"></div>
<form action="/">
   <input type="text" />
   <br/>
   <input type="text" /> 
   <button>ok</button>
</form>
<div style="height:300px;"></div>
```

When I click on input in the bottom on the page, keyboard open and hide input.
[image: example]

I open from my phone w3s site ant on them when I click on input when it of the bottom of the page browser automatically scrolled it into view. 
[image: w3s site]

What I need to do that automatic scroll into view of focus input will start work on my demo ?

Comment: You should find this to be helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586366/3011082). Tell me what happens :)

Comment: I know this way, but I think this is default browser feature now, because on any site it wokrs properly, but not on my :)

Answer (score 0):

I sloved the problem. In my case it was because the body height was smaller then content height. And on codepen I think it was because it render via iframe.