# Javascript auto-scroll to div

Tags: javascript

so ive been looking at different articles on stack overflow and can't seem to find what im looking for.

So I just realized that the css property scroll-behavior doesn't work on safari/ ios browsers. So now im thinking i should use javascript to solve this.

This is what ive tried but it doesn't actually scroll it still jumps to the section, which means the scrollIntoView isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
function subnav_link_click1(){
    var subnav_link_value = document.getElementById('subnav_link_id1').href;
    subnav_link_value.scrollIntoView(true)
}
```

Comment: why are you doing `.href` when selecting the element ? Plus you should call it like this `element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})`

Comment: You may want to think about using jQuery, as it has this very nifty "animate" function, plus several built-in functions (like *toggle* and/or fadeIn/Out). Also for animated scrolling, you can find a solution (I use a version of this) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery

Comment: im using .href so i can scroll to the href link value typed in instead of hard coding the div value in. I've now tried this subnav_link_value.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"}); and it still doesnt work. hmmm....

Answer (score 0):

```js
const scrollUp = () => {
   const anchorEl = document.getElementById('myId');
  anchorEl.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end',  behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

```css
.container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
}

.container .btn-holder {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a href="https://google.com" id="myId">google</a>
 <button class="btn-holder" onclick="scrollUp()">scroll up</button>
</div>
```

You have an example of how it should work here.

Scrollintoview - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: ye i cant get that to work either. also scrollIntoViewOptions aren't compatible on ios .... is this possible? it seems like it should be